# Help with timed signal circuit

Tags: capacitor, switches, timer

I need to design a circuit capable of sending an on signal for 5 seconds and then shut off. The circuit needs to be initiated on power input from a usb port (5v ~200mA), and as I said output a few seconds of current before shutting off permanently, and then of course do the same again when power is switched off and on again.

Does anybody have ideas on how to set this up? I would prefer not to use any IC's like the 555 timer if possible, just basic components (eg capacitors, transistors...).

Comment: Duh - how much current (or is it signal?) does it need to provide for 5 seconds? What are its available power supplies from "power input"? And are you also opposed to transistors?

Comment: You will need to explain a bit more. The power that is being inputed, is it DC? What is the voltage or range? And the output of the circuit under discussion, what is it being used for or used by? Is it just a signal that controls something else? Or are you also asking for help on the power switching part of this?

Comment: You can't get a signal with definitive edges using only resistors and capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

5 seconds is a very long time from the perspective of RC circuits.  I suspect you'll need a timer IC, or at least an op amp.  First thing that comes to mind is [LM555](http://www.ti.com/product/LM555).  If you need to supply more power, you could have the timer drive a power mosfet

Comment: I disagree. As long as the OP does not need precision, an RC timer could work fine. For example, 1 Meg with 10 uF is a 10 second time constant.

Answer (score 0):

This works quite nicely; change the width of the output pulse by changing R1 or C1.

$$ \tau = \text {1.1 R1}\times \text C1 $$

[image]